# How to create EditText with rounded corners?

Tags: android, view, android-edittext, rounded-corners, android-shapedrawable

How to create an `EditText` that has rounded corners instead of the default rectangular-shaped corners?

Answer (score 633, accepted):

There is an easier way than the one written by CommonsWare. Just create a drawable resource that specifies the way the `EditText` will be drawn:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" 
    android:padding="10dp">

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

Then, just reference this drawable in your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <EditText  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You will get something like:

[image]

#### Edit

Based on Mark's comment, I want to add the way you can create different states for your `EditText`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- res/drawable/rounded_edittext_states.xml -->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_focused" />
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_focused" />
    <item 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_edittext" />
</selector>
```

These are the states:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- res/drawable/rounded_edittext_focused.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FF0000" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

And... now, the `EditText` should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <EditText  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_states"
        android:padding="5dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Except that your solution uses the same drawable for all states. A regular `EditText` has different backgrounds for focused, disabled, pressed, and selected, besides the default. Focused, in particular, may be important going forward if we get some Android devices that lack touchscreens, like Google TV.

Comment: This is great! It works fine on the device but prevents the 'Graphical Layout' view from displaying my activity when I include the rounded edit box. The error log gives me a 'UnsupportedOperationException:null'.  Any ideas?

Comment: Good to know... actually I don't know how to fix it. I guess it's an Eclipse's ADT bug.

Comment: excellent answer. When I try to do it with latest ADT, nothing happens but the UI design screen becomes kind of shaded.. bit annyoing though. But excelent answer. SAved me from my boss :)

Comment: A slight fix, change android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_focused" to android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_edittext_focused"

Comment: if your radius is same for all the 4 corners use `android:radius` instead of defining 4 lines

Comment: How come I am seeing the green underline bar ? Is there a way to hide it without setting the background color to transparent ?

Comment: You must use `<corners android:radius="10dp" />` instead of defining it for all corners. Otherwise "Path.isConvex is not supported" error will be shown while rendering image.

Answer (score 134):

Here is the same solution (with some extra bonus code) in just one XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/edittext_rounded_corners.xml -->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_focused="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#FF8000"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="2.3dp"
            android:color="#FF8000" />
         <corners
            android:radius="15dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_focused="false">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#FF8000"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="2.3dp"
            android:color="#FF8000" />      
        <corners
            android:radius="15dp" />       
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="2.3dp"
            android:color="#FF8000" />  
        <corners
            android:radius="15dp" />                          
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="false">
    <shape>
        <gradient 
            android:startColor="#F2F2F2"
            android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:angle="270"
        />
        <stroke
            android:width="0.7dp"                
            android:color="#BDBDBD" /> 
        <corners
            android:radius="15dp" />            
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_enabled="true">
    <shape>
        <padding 
                android:left="4dp"
                android:top="4dp"
                android:right="4dp"
                android:bottom="4dp"
            />
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

You then just set the background attribute to edittext_rounded_corners.xml file:

```
<EditText  android:id="@+id/editText_name"
      android:background="@drawable/edittext_rounded_corners"/>
```

Comment: getting error as "0.5dp" in attribute "width" is not a valid format.

Comment: I tried using the above solution but unfortunately, while I just set `topRightRadius`and `topLeftRadius` all four corners end up rounded. Please help. :(

Answer (score 46):

Try this one,

1. Create `rounded_edittext.xml` file in your Drawable

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="15dp">

       <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
       <corners
           android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
           android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
           android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
           android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
       <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#f06060" />
   </shape>
   ```
2. Apply background for your `EditText` in xml file

   ```
   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/edit_expiry_date"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="10dip"
       android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
       android:hint="@string/shop_name"
       android:inputType="text" />
   ```
3. You will get output like this

[image]

Comment: Sachin your output image shows square corners not rounded one's as requested by questioner.  This might be a good way to get the box to have an outline.

Comment: @JesseBoyd, Your concern is right but rounded_edittext in this xml file just change the values of all Radius as per your requirement.

Answer (score 20):

Thanks for Norfeldt's answer. I slightly changed its gradient for a better inner shadow effect.

```
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="false">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:centerY="0.2"
            android:startColor="#D3D3D3"
            android:centerColor="#65FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"
            android:angle="270"
            />
        <stroke
            android:width="0.7dp"
            android:color="#BDBDBD" />
        <corners
            android:radius="15dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Looks great in a light backgrounded layout..

[image]

Answer (score 7):

By my way of thinking, it already has rounded corners.

In case you want them more rounded, you will need to:

1. Clone all of the nine-patch PNG images that make up an `EditText` background (found in your SDK)
2. Modify each to have more rounded corners
3. Clone the XML `StateListDrawable` resource that combines those `EditText` backgrounds into a single `Drawable`, and modify it to point to your more-rounded nine-patch PNG files
4. Use that new `StateListDrawable` as the background for your `EditText` widget

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to the other answers, I found that the simplest solution to achieve the rounded corners was to set the following as a background to your Edittext.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>

</shape>
```

Answer (score 6):

With the Material Components Library you can use the [**`MaterialShapeDrawable`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/MaterialShapeDrawable) to [draw custom shapes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md).

With a **`EditText`** you can do:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        ../>
```

Then create a `MaterialShapeDrawable`:

```
float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius);

EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
//Apply the rounded corners 
ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = new ShapeAppearanceModel()
                .toBuilder()
                .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
                .build();

MaterialShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = 
            new MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel);
//Apply a background color
shapeDrawable.setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color.white));
//Apply a stroke
shapeDrawable.setStroke(2.0f, ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorAccent));

ViewCompat.setBackground(editText,shapeDrawable);
```

[image]

It requires the version **1.1.0** of the library.

Answer (score 4):

If you want only corner should curve not whole end, then use below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="3dp" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="@color/White"
        android:startColor="@color/White" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/Gray" />

</shape>
```

It will only curve the four angle of `EditText`.