# How to create edit text with rounded corners in android

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me how to create an editable textbox with rounded corners in android?

I tried with this code but it's not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

Thanks

Comment: Before OS 2.3, android edit text used to have a rounded cornered background. So what you can do is, copy the older background image in your res folder and then set it manually in your xml file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hey have a look about the problem in this discussion : [How to create EditText with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646415/how-to-create-edittext-with-rounded-corners) ..I am sure it will surely gonna help you.

Answer (score 6):

Just create an xml file in your **drawable** folder name as **round_corner.xml**.And add this following code.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
            android:radius="3dp"
             />
        <solid
            android:color="@android:color/white"/>

    </shape>
```

At Last you add this xml in **background** property of your **Edittext** as follows:-

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/ed1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
 />
```

Done..Definitely it works..

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!-- res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml --> 
<shape xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp"> <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" > 

<corners android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:topLeftRadius="15dp" android:topRightRadius="15dp" /> 

</shape>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#ECE9E6"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:angle="270"
        />
    <corners
        android:radius="15dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#ffffff"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="4dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"
        />
</shape>
```