# How to draw rounded rectangle in Android UI?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I need to draw a rounded rectangle in the Android UI. Having the same rounded rectangle for `TextView` and `EditText` would also be helpful.

Comment: Have a look at this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646415/how-to-create-edittext-with-rounded-corners

Comment: atleast you should put the picture.. because if someone is looking for same question than it will be easy to understand.

Comment: if you want addionnal accuracy, go [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65450741/to-draw-rounded-rectangle-in-android).

Answer (score 268, accepted):

In your layout xml do the following:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

    <corners android:radius="32dp" />

</shape>
```

By changing the `android:radius` you can change the amount of "radius" of the corners.

`<solid>` is used to define the color of the drawable.

You can use replace `android:radius` with `android:bottomLeftRadius`, `android:bottomRightRadius`, `android:topLeftRadius` and `android:topRightRadius` to define radius for each corner.

Comment: They didn't ask for a gradient.  Don't know why this is accepted answer.

Comment: I guess it was accepted because it was there several months before most of the other answers. I haven't done any Android development for years, so I have no idea how the answer could be changed or updated now to remove the gradient, although I'm guessing the "solid" tag as used in Noundla Sandeep's reply below would probably do the trick.

Answer (score 128):

I think, this is you exactly needed.

Here drawable(xml) file that creates rounded rectangle.
**round_rect_shape.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp" />

</shape>
```

**Here layout file: my_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_rect_shape"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Something text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

-> In the above code, LinearLayout having the background(That is the key role to place to create rounded rectangle). 
So you can place any view like TextView, EditText... in that LinearLayout to see background as round rectangle for all.

Comment: Is there a way to abstract this? I want to be able to use `android:background="@drawable/round_rect_shape"` in my styles.xml, but to use different background colors by setting another property. Is there any option except creating an identical drawable for each color?

Comment: You can make any shape rounded with this way!

Answer (score 22):

In `monodroid`, you can do like this for rounded rectangle, and then keeping this as a parent class, `editbox` and other layout features can be added.

```
 class CustomeView : TextView
    {
       public CustomeView (Context context, IAttributeSet ) : base (context, attrs)  
        {  
        }
       public CustomeView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)  
        {  
        }
       protected override void OnDraw(Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
       {
           base.OnDraw(canvas);
           Paint p = new Paint();
           p.Color = Color.White;
           canvas.DrawColor(Color.DarkOrange);

           Rect rect = new Rect(0,0,3,3);

           RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);


           canvas.DrawRoundRect( rectF, 1,1, p);



       }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" /> 
    <corners
      android:bottomLeftRadius="500dp"
      android:bottomRightRadius="500dp"
      android:topLeftRadius="500dp"
      android:topRightRadius="500dp" />
</shape>
```

Now, in which element you  want to use this shape just add:
`android:background="@drawable/custom_round_ui_shape"`

Create a new XML in drawable named "custom_round_ui_shape"

Answer (score 3):

Right_click on the drawable and create new layout xml file in the name of for example button_background.xml.
then copy and paste the following code.
You can change it according your need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners
android:radius="14dp" />
<solid android:color="@color/colorButton" />
<padding
android:bottom="0dp"
android:left="0dp"
android:right="0dp"
android:top="0dp" />
<size
android:width="120dp"
android:height="40dp" />
</shape>
```

Now you can use it.

```
<Button
android:background="@drawable/button_background"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just define a new xml background in the drawables folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="enter_your_desired_color_here" />
<corners android:radius="enter_your_desired_radius_the_corners" />
</shape>
```

After this just include it in your TextView or EditText 
by defining it in the background.

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/textView"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="80dp"
 android:background="YOUR_FILE_HERE"
 Android:layout_weight="1"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:text="TEXT_HERE"
 android:textSize="40sp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **CardView** for Round Rectangle. CardView give more functionality like cardCornerRadius, cardBackgroundColor, cardElevation & many more. CardView make UI more suitable then Custom Round Rectangle drawable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

I tried several methods and can say that you should also add [View.setClipToOutline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26182454/2914140) (API >= 21):

```
textView.clipToOutline = true
```

In this case you won't get a rectangular selection below `TextView` (it occurs on some devices) like below:

[image]

[Some people](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37199989/2914140) wrap a rectangle with `CardView`. It works, but on some old devices it shows wrong corners, if radius is large enough:

[image]

In `TextView` you can also add this attribute:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
```

It will show darker gray selection when click light gray text labels.

Answer (score -1):

```
    paint.apply {
        strokeWidth = lineWidth.toFloat()
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        color = lineColor
        ***strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND***
    }
```