# design a custom view like a tool tip

Tags: android, custom-component

Does any one have any idea of creating a custom component like the below image instead of using the image itself.
I know how to create a rectangle (a rounded one using the xml and not in java) which was discussed in the [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618402/how-to-draw-rounded-rectangle-in-android-ui) but i am not able to work with something like the pointer part.

does anyone have an idea to do this i would be happy if i am suggested.

[image]

Comment: May be using a image on the bottom of a a layeredview. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961944/overlapping-views-in-android

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i was not looking for something that works out with images but looking for a way to draw this one so that i can change the colors when ever i need by just passing a parameter of the color code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class that extends PopupWindow and set the background through code so that you can replace its color.

Here is a easy sample PopupWindow: http://www.ceveni.com/2009/09/popup-window-in-android-sample-program.html

See this post to know how to change/replace colors in a drawable: [How to change colors of a Drawable in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309629/how-to-change-colors-of-a-drawable-in-android)

The `adjust()` method from that post is enough for you.
Create a new `PopupWindow`, load the bg drawable, change its color and set the new drawable to the popupWindow.

Comment: This is almost what i am looking for.  You helped me to make my work easy :) The adjust() method didnt help me but i got an idea from the link you suggested. Thank you Very Much userSeven7s.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of customized popup window. I never tried it before but you can give a try If you succeed please share it here....

Comment: Thanks for the response.I  didnt get any idea to work out this. So thought of taking some help. And actually that's not a pop up like dialog but just a way to display a message.