# Styling Linear Layout with multi edit text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am trying to make a LinearLayout with several EditText for inputting fields like this:

[image: check here]

I checked several answers here to make a custom drawable for the EditText but how can I make it for the whole linear layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a single `LinearLayout`.
You need minimum 2 `LinearLayout`s with horizontal orientation, and one `LinearLayout` with vertial orientation, that contains those two.

And you can set the borders for your `EditText`s with shape `Drawable`s.
See examples here: [How to draw rounded rectangle in Android UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618402/how-to-draw-rounded-rectangle-in-android-ui)

Comment: what about the name of the edit text, how can I make it look like the pic ( top left corner of each edittext ) ?

Comment: @circler as a suggestion - android:drawableLeft="@drawable/pic"

Comment: What about the TextView ( which is the title of each EditText ), how can I make it look like the picture ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below code ,You can also inclue textview inside it,

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.55" 
                android:background="@drawable/selector"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.15" 
                android:background="@drawable/selector"/>


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.30" 
                android:background="@drawable/selector"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.20" 
                android:background="@drawable/selector"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.20" 
                android:background="@drawable/selector"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.60"
                android:background="@drawable/selector" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


where selector drawable is xml file inside xml folder

selector.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle">

       <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />


      <stroke 
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black"
       />


      <padding
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp" />
    </shape>
```

Comment: how can I make the title of the fields look similar as in the picture ?