# How to create shapes triangle in android

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

How to get this effects in android in file.xml?

[image: FirstPicture]

and

[image: SecondaryPicture]

Comment: Do you mean [Rounded Rectangles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618402/how-to-draw-rounded-rectangle-in-android-ui)

Comment: Yes.. but i need to join 2x colors look at picture i don't now how i can make it. Now i got this: http://postimg.org/image/ytu1527zd/
I need red rounded rectangles on bottom and all black rounded rectangles on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an xml layer list drawable and put the two rectangles on top of each other.  In the corners tag of your xml drawable use the topLeftRadius, topRightRadius, bottomLeftRadius, and bottomRightRadius to control whether each corner is rounded independently.