# Android rectangle with a curved edge

Tags: android, canvas, android-drawable

I'm looking for a simple solution to to draw a rectangle with one edge that is curved. I'm trying to avoid creating a custom rectangle class and manually drawing it as I believe there's a much simpler solution that I have not considered. I have attached an image of the design I wish to create. Thank you in advance 
[image]

edit:
 I was thinking it maybe easier to round the white rectangle but I'm open to rounding the purple one. 
[image]

Comment: @AdamRatzman there's a picture. The purple outline. One of the sides of the rectangle, the longer one obviously.

Comment: @AdamRatzman The pink one with convex edge, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and play with oval shape and insets.
Example:

```
<_inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:insetBottom="-20dp"
       android:insetLeft="-20dp"
       android:insetRight="-20dp">

    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
    </shape>

</inset>
```

I got a result similar to what you need with this

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question, this existing answer on SO solves your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9885817.

However, if that doesn't solve your problem, I believe that you can define an android:gradient and there are existing attributes that can curve sides.

Sorry I don't have a more detailed answer, I'm just waking up now lol

Comment: Yeah this was a surprisingly easy solution. I just set the values a bit higher and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much

Comment: No problem :) Good luck on your project!