# Trapezoid drawable like in the picture?

Tags: android, android-layout

I  want to design a xml layout as in the picture. So far I have rectangle shape how to make that sharp corners  from xml.
[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke android:width="0dp" android:color="#4c71f5" />
    <padding android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp" />
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Instead of this create  `svg` background and try it.

Comment: ... or a 9 patch.

Comment: This post helped me a lot in creating a trapezium view 
https://arkapp.medium.com/trapezium-view-for-android-584799c7e849

With the help of this I was able to create a custom view with one edge as a slope.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below:

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <gradient
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners
        android:radius="3dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

and refer to this link, [Good Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618402/how-to-draw-rounded-rectangle-in-android-ui)

Comment: Now I'm curious to learn how a **rounded rectangle** will become a **trapezoid**...

Comment: @JNI_OnLoad Tried it didn't help need to create something like show in the  picture still I am struggling with it