# Rounded corners on all Buttons in Theme - how to override?

Tags: android, button, themes

I have been looking around for an easy way to make *all buttons in my entire app* have rounded corners.

I haven't succeeded, so I thought I'd ask =)

**My AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/BlackTheme" android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" android:name="MyApplication">
```

**My styles.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="ButtonHeader" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:textSize">18dip</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">70dip</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">20dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">30dip</item>
    </style>

    <style name="JobViewHeader" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BlackTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
        <item name="android:button">@drawable/button_rounded</item>
    </style>  

    <style name="DialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    </style>  
</resources>
```

**My button_rounded.xml (in drawables):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <corners android:radius="10dp" /> 
</shape>
```

Comment: You could change them all to `ImageButtons` and use a 9-patched drawable of a rounded corner box made in PowerPoint.  :)

Comment: So, what problem you are getting?

Comment: @LalitPoptani THe problem is that the buttons are unchanged, they are not rounded at all.

Comment: @cornbreadninja Nah, no 9-patches please. Thats a horrible way to work... should work with the radius on corners, somehow...

Comment: Check this though this is for editText http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646415/how-to-create-edittext-with-rounded-corners/3646629#3646629

Comment: @Ted, at the risk of veering off into discussion-land, why do you feel it's a horrible way to work?  draw-9 patch is a system utility.

Comment: @cornbreadninja Because you need to create the damn images, which is extremely time-consuming and messy. I prefer just changing a few characters in an XML file, and thats it. To create images, for something this easy, is just way to much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are trying to specify some abstract drawable ([Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) in your case) as a button background, which will be combined later with any other drawable set as a button background. Unfortunately, this is impossible. If you want a background with rounded corners, you need to provide drawable resource which does contain rounded corners, no matter what type of drawable it is: Shape Drawable, nine-patch, etc.

However you may consider subclassing the `Button` widget and overriding its `draw` method, where you can manipulate button's look as you wish.

Comment: Hmmm, so setting the background to a drawable with rounded corners would work? Maybe even something like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3646629/175830 ?

Comment: Yes, why not? Use Shape Drawable, for example:

`<shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF707070"/>
            <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#Ffff" />
        </shape>`

And set it as a button's background.

Comment: Ok, that should work as long as I can still get the button depressed visual and everything.