# How to change the style of an Android widget button programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-button

I would like to change the style of an Android widget button (specifically the corners) completely programmatically.  Meaning, I would like to do it without any xml files at all.  From my research I am coming to the conclusion that this is not posible.  Is my conclusion correct or does someone know how it might be done?

Answer (score 6):

You should look at the inherited methods from TextView and View of Button:

```
setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

to name one... you can also change the layoutparams of the button object, which gives you access to all the xml attributes normally accessible. In general, you can do everything programmatically that you can do in the xml.

If that isn't enough, you can extend the Button class and override the onDraw method to change how android draws your button

EDIT:

Maybe you can add an xml theme much like this thread suggests: [How to programmatically setting style attribute in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016249/how-to-programmatically-setting-style-attribute-in-a-view)

and then in it set

and add the theme programmatically to the button?
I haven't done much work with themes, so I can't attest to whether this will definitely work

Comment: I put padding as just another example but I guess I shouldn't have since I hadn't done the proper research on it.  I have been specifically trying to change the corners.  I am looking into using setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams params).  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think this is the case? Taking one of your items as an example, here's a method to [set padding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

For corners you can use a drawable with a shape with rounded corners. See the [documentation for drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#corners-element). There are also many [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646415/how-to-create-edittext-with-rounded-corners) (with answers) on StackOverflow about this too. If you want to do it programmatically there is the [RoundedRectShape](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/RoundRectShape.html).