# Rounded Button in Android

Tags: android, android-button, rounded-corners

I want to create rounded buttons in an Android program. I have looked at  [How to create EditText with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646415/how-to-create-edittext-with-rounded-corners/3646629#3646629)

What I want to achieve is:

1. Rounded Edge Buttons
2. Change Button background/appearance on different states (Like Onclick, Focus)
3. Use my own PNG for the background and not create a shape.

Comment: http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/customize-button-in-android/

Comment: Google have new framework,
new technologies is better [Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round/64087445#64087445)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can do a rounded corner button without resorting to an ImageView.

A background selector resource, `button_background.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <!--  Non focused states 
      --> 
      <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_unfocused" /> 
      <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_unfocused" /> 
     <!--  Focused states 
      --> 
      <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_focus" /> 
      <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_focus" /> 
     <!--  Pressed 
      --> 
      <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_press" /> 
    </selector>
```

For each state, a drawable resource, e.g. button_press.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF404040" /> 
  <corners android:radius="6dp" /> 
  <gradient android:startColor="#FF6800" android:centerColor="#FF8000" android:endColor="#FF9700" android:angle="90" /> 
</shape>
```

Note the `corners` element, this gets you rounded corners!

Then set the background drawable on the button:

```
android:background="@drawable/button_background"
```

**EDIT (9/2018)**: The same technique can be used to create a circular button.  A circle is really just a square button with radius size set to 1/2 the side of the square

Additionally, in the example above the `stroke` and `gradient` aren't necessary elements, they are just examples and ways that you'll be able to see the rounded corner shape

Comment: CSMith. I got the selector working. I am a bit confused by the second part as to where to put the code. Do I create a separate xml file. If so how do i call it? I am assuming for the button, I still set it's background to @drawable/button_background... Thx

Comment: yes, set the background to button_background, and you'll have an xml file for each "state" in your selection, the second part is an example button_press.xml.

Comment: CSmith. So where is this separate xml file being called. In the example above you have the background set to a drawable object and that works great to get the background to change on interaction. However, the button is not rounded unless you create the png. with rounded corners and use nine patch to avoid distortion.

Comment: What if I need to add custom font to my button text too?

Comment: The background drawable selector has nothing to do with the text font.  This android:background could be used on both a standard Button and an ImageButton.

Comment: So, I am really new at this but, if I understand you correctly CSmith you're saying to replicate the <shape> resource and rename (and tweak) it for each of the 4 button states? So, total of 5 resource files for this case?

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno, assuming you want different styling for the various button states (i.e. selected, pressed, etc), you'd need separate drawable resources for each.

Comment: I'm pretty new to android development and this question might come out pretty damn naive: Which `drawable` folder should I add the XML file to? I've got four different `drawable` folders: `drawable-hdpi`; `drawable-mdpi`; `drawable-xhdpi`; `drawable-xxhdpi`.

Comment: @ikartik90, use drawable.  The other folders in general are used to override settings found in the "base" drawable folder for density specific assets or settings, and in this example there aren't any density specific overrides present.

Comment: Why are there 2 of each?

Comment: for me. at present adding a selector to a button does nothing. i can get the selector added to a textview and use it like a button and it works fine. just doesnt seem to change the colouring etc of the button?

Comment: what about button_unfocused and button_focus drawables?

Answer (score 87):

If you need a rounded button in Android, then create an XML file "RoundShapeBtn.xml" as drawable.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">   
  <solid android:color="#6E6E6E"/> <!-- this one is ths color of the Rounded Button -->
  <corners
   android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
   android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
   android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
   android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Add this to your button code:

```
android:background="@drawable/RoundShapeBtn"
```

Comment: Do I add the font face here too in case I want the button text to be of a particular font?

Comment: @GarimaTiwari   yes you can do this and much more in designing related

Comment: Actually you get a build error if you name the file with CapitalLettersInTheName.. :)

Comment: "Cannot resolve class solid"
"Cannot resolve class corners"
"Cannot resolve class shape"

Answer (score 20):

create xml file in drawable folder in android like :

> rounded_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="20dp"/> // if you want clear round shape then make radius size is half of your  button`s height.
    <solid android:color="#EEFFFFFF"/> // Button Colour
    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="5dp"/>

</shape>
```

> Now this xml file as your buttons background.

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
```

Comment: This is a what most people are looking for actually. Very curved smooth rectangular edges. How can I put a shadow on the button? Thanks!

Comment: Stellar! If anyone is annoyed at having to make separate rounded button XMLs to get different colors, you can remove the `solid android:color` from the drawable XML, and instead specify colors using `android:backgroundTint` for each `Button`

Comment: @K_7 if you do that, you lose the elevation and shadow. just follow this one you would get elevation and shadow when you hold on the button.

Answer (score 6):

Extend `ImageView` like so:

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {
  private static final String TAG = "RoundedImageView";

  private float mRadius = 0f;

  public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    // retrieve styles attributes
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RoundedView);
    mRadius = a.getDimension(R.styleable.RoundedView_radius, 0f);
    a.recycle();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // only do this if we actually have a radius
    if(mRadius > 0) {
      RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
      Path clipPath = new Path();
      clipPath.addRoundRect(rect, mRadius, mRadius, Path.Direction.CW);
      canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
  }
}
```

And apply your normal background resource to it and it should be clipped with rounded corners.

Comment: are there R.styleable.RoundedView_radius and  R.styleable.RoundedView by default?

Comment: Cody, how can i view the source code for android.widget.imageview.class. I keep getting do you want to attach a source file to it because it was not found in eclipse.

Comment: @Jib you can access the Android source code at: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Comment: Thanks Cody, this programmatic solution is what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using the corner attribute. Look at the below xml.

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:height="1.0dip"
            android:width="1.0dip"
            android:color="#ffee82ee" />

        <solid android:color="#ffee82ee" />

        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="102.0dip"
            android:bottomRightRadius="102.0dip"
            android:radius="102.0dip"
            android:topLeftRadius="102.0dip"
            android:topRightRadius="102.0dip" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's much better to put the button states and shapes in 1 xml selector file. That should make your app run faster/better. Try this (courtesy of Introduction to Android Application Development). Not spamming here just showing this isn't my code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
     <corners android:radius="12dip" />
     <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#333333" />
     <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#333333"      android:endColor="#555555"  />            
    </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
     <corners android:radius="12dip" />
     <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#333333" />
     <solid android:color="#58857e"/>       
    </shape>
    </item>  
    <item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
     <corners android:radius="12dip" />
     <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#333333" />
     <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#333333" android:endColor="#555555" />            
    </shape>
    </item>

    </selector>
```

P.S.-design tip: gradients and rounded rectangles are best used when you can hardly tell they are there-use wisely.

Answer (score 3):

[It is recommended by Google](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html) that you do not mimic UI elements from other platforms. I wouldn't put rounded iOS style buttons in an Android application.

Comment: It's not our fault that the devs decided to put an ugly UI as the standard.

Comment: This is a bit after the old, but I thought I'd add to anyone reading that my previous company's app was nearly not featured on the app store due to a lot of iOS UI styling. We had to revise and put in the appropriate Material design considerations. Always important to follow the guidelines!

Comment: @lase completely disagree the guidelines are just that, they are not hard rules

Comment: @martinseal1987 well, as loose as rules may be, i'm just providing future readers anecdotal evidence that the platform holders *do* care about style consistency, which is perhaps obvious through the answer's link to the style guide and the large section on cross platform implementation. feel free to roll the dice!

Comment: @lase the playstore would never deny your app for not sticking to the guidelines, they are not rules in any sense of the word

Comment: @martinseal1987 getting your application "featured" and "approved" are entirely different concepts.

Comment: @lase an important distinction I honestly missed, however games would be an easy exception to your point

Comment: Lemme just go tell my UI designers...

Answer (score 2):

Rounded buttons can be creating using ring shape drawable also, see  http://www.zoftino.com/android-shape-drawable-examples

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="40dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <padding android:bottom="50dp"
        android:left="16dp"
        android:right="16dp"
        android:top="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create Drawable resource named btnOval-->then past code ;

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="oval"  
android:padding="10dp">   
      <solid android:color="#6E6E6E"/> 
    </shape>
```

and user inside button tag like,

```
<Button
andorid:width=""
android:hieght=""
android:background="@Drawable/btnOval"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code
Create a drawable file called **circular_button.xml** and insert the below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#008577" />
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="100dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
    android:topRightRadius="100dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="100dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then change the background of the button to this drawable file

```
 <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
                android:text="Button"/>
```

If you want a full circle button you can use the below drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="#008577"/>

    <size
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```