# Android button woth rounded corners and changable background color

Tags: android, button, rounded-corners

I want to create all of my buttons with rounded corners and different background colors. I've already searched about how to create rounded corners:
[Rounded Button in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334618/rounded-button-android)
[How to make a round button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266595/how-to-make-a-round-button)

but the problem is that I have to create an XML file for every color of my buttons. I want to know if there is a way to have a simple XML for all ,y buttons with different background colors and size?

Comment: I suggest to create the image background for your buttons with rounded/coloured or anything you like and a single xml file for the states of those background, applying to your buttons. That's the simplest and quickest way rather than create by xml yourself.

Comment: One xml containing all selectors and colors for all buttons ? That I know of, this is not possible. You need to define your colors in colors.xml, your background images in xml drawables, and your buttons backgrounds as xml selectors.

Comment: I would also add that rounded buttons is not exactly standard practice in Android, the design guidelines show you straight corners or borderless buttons : http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/buttons.html