# Android rounded button with images

Tags: android, android-button

I wanted to create a rounded button in Android with varying images for the background. These images will be downloaded from the internet...and the shape of the images vary (square, rectangle, etc.). Is there anyway to achieve this with just a `Button`?

I read the following posts:

[Rounded Button in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334618/rounded-button-android)

[How to make the corners of a button round?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round)

Problem with those implementations is that they only allow for a certain background to be applied. Is there anyway to do this with the background being the image I set but still with rounded corners? My only alternative to this is to have an invisible button on top of an `ImageView`...but i'd rather not go that route if I can avoid it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a good library:

https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

This library makes it easy to have rounded images inside the imageview.