# Custom rounded button in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button

Can anyone tell me how I can create a custom rounded button in Android (like the one you see in the middle of the picture)?

[image]

Comment: You can just set the circular background image for Button.

Comment: Refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334618/rounded-button-android

Comment: in this image which is button

Comment: All three are buttons, but I don't know how to make the rounded one in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Every** `View` on Android is a rectangle. Considering your picture, let's take a look at the `Views` (the lines represent `View` bounds):

[image]

The trick is that the big round `Button` in the middle simply overlaps the other two in some particular `Layout`. I've quickly tested this assumption and was able to achieve pretty much the same result, here's a screenshot illustrating how this can be done quite easily:

[image]

Comment: @poitroae sorry, but this is a 2-yers old answer and I don't have any related code. And as far as I remember *I didn't have* any code, as you can see on the screenshot this is just a simple visual editor mock up

Answer (score 0):

you can use this online button generator which also makes rounded buttons http://angrytools.com/android/button/