# Android studio layout editor not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13872391/7759878) guide on how to make a rounded button. work totally fine but somehow my layout editor stop working after I added the file. I can normally edit using the normal text but I cant drag around things in the editor.  I tried to restart android studio and things work fine again. But once I open the rounded button xml file in the drawable, the editor stop working again.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: noted that I didn't put the file name in caps. all in small letters

Comment: Ive also found out that whatever xml file I put under drawable. this problem will happen when I open the file.

Answer (score 0):

I just invalidated and restarted the cache and it worked.