# Rounded Button in Android Without Expanding Size

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-button, rounded-corners, android-background

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334618/rounded-button-in-android) post has plenty of answers that explain how to create a rounded button in Android. But almost all of the answers end up expanding the size of the button.

For instance, in this layout, notice how the top button (the one with the rounded corners) has significantly more padding then the rest of the buttons.

[image: Screenshot]

Here's the code for a button without rounded corners;

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/useKeyboardButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/use_keyboard_msg"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/privacyPolicyButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/enableKeyboardButton"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    />
```

And here's the code for a button with rounded corners:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/enableKeyboardButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/enable_keyboard_msg"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/useKeyboardButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
    />
```

where the background is this drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the style attribute and only setting the background drawable.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with newer support library (v28) `MaterialButton`.

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="MATERIAL BUTTON"
android:textSize="18sp"
app:icon="@drawable/ic_android_white_24dp" />
```

Take a look at [this great article](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-the-v28-android-design-support-library-2c96c6031ae8)

Answer (score 0):

Use [MaterialButton](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/)

and add `app:cornerRadius="8dp"`for rounded corner