# Android: Difference in appearance

Tags: android, android-version

hope this will be a quick easy question, I've just tried my app on my old phone and it looks better (personal oppinion) on my older HTC Desire then my newer Samsung SII. The main part is the rounding of corners on most things. Do you know where that is coming from? Manufacture or Droid Version? and can I force the rounded corners without resorting to massive amounts of effort on the samsung, and I presume most handsets?

HTC is v2.2.2 
samsung is v2.3.4

[image: <code>HTC Desire</code>]

[image: Samsung SII]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing here are manufacturer specific themes. HTC Devices run the so called [Sense UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Sense). While on Samsung devices you find [TouchWiz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TouchWiz).
If you want to have the Sense UI look & feel on Samsung Devices you indeed need to resort to (massive) amounts of efforts by creating your own theme or custom widget styles.

Cheers 
Renard

Comment: This is what I feared (very scared now) I have to say (and this is off topic) but Apple have done a lot right here and Google have made life very difficult for developers. oh well, I better get typing.... cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know Samsung has implemented his own Android interface, such as HTC. The image quality is due to the difference between HDPI, MDPI and LDPI scrrens.

The best way to get rounded corners is to create a new style for you widgets.
Google something like "android:background style spinner".

Regards.

Comment: I found this but was having problems with overriding the disabled state, which is why I was looking for an 'easier' solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646415/how-to-create-edittext-with-rounded-corners

Comment: I don't think there is an easier solution except the use of a rounded corner image with a bigger z-index than your widget. You should search in that way with a relative layout and a transparent rounded corners image.