# How to set style for EditText?

Tags: android

I'm developing some Android application, and I need to change style of EditText. I use 4.0 version, and I need to set border width, border color and background color, and rounded corners. How can I do it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you links to acheive what you've asked.

**Custom background and border** : [Changing background color and border color of an EditText widget using State List in Android](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/changing-background-color-and-border-color-of-an-edittext-widget-using-state-list-in-android/)

**Rounded Corners** : [How to create EditText with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646415/how-to-create-edittext-with-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you follow the [Beginners Tutorial from Google](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html), which covers all the necessary steps to get you up and running. Then you will also come accross [this section](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html) where you learn how to set the visual appearance of Views via XML style files. You can also set all the visual properties programmatically, but this is generally discouraged, as you want to **separate the presentation from application logic**.