# Android editTexts and Buttons like IOS in material design

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, material-design

How we can do this like the below image on EditText and Button in material design on Android ?

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: Those do not match the Material Design style.

Comment: using xml style for button and editText (with-rounded-corners)

Comment: @ZiedRebhi example please - CommonsWare - are you sure we cannot design this?

Comment: see this answer for button with rounded corners : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18879660/2337837

Comment: and this an example for EditText http://stackoverflow.com/a/6895823/2337837

Comment: and what about the editTexts background like the above picture?

Comment: EditText with Transparent Background : `android:background="@null"`;)

Answer (score 1):

Create a xml with the below code in drawable and set it as your edittext bg..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
<solid android:color="#00FFFFFF"/>
<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
 <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find what you want here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#Style

Answer (score 0):

Use this `xml` for the `EditText`, remove transparent and add color for `Button`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners android:radius="30dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="@android:color/white" />
 </shape>
```