# How to add curved underline to an Edittext or a Searchview?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-custom-view, android-theme, searchview

[image: editext image]

I want to create a searchview if possible or an edittext similar to that, i beleive It's in holo theme but my project theme is Appcompact, thnx.

Comment: try using custom background using xml drawable for edittext

Comment: thanks, but that is my problem I don't know how to exactly make that.

Comment: Refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646415/how-to-create-edittext-with-rounded-corners) on how to make a editText with rounded corners

Comment: @rawa300 after using xml drawable then using clip drawable

Comment: thanks guys I believe this will do the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

in your layout file

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="EditText"
    android:padding="8dp"
    />
```

edit_text_drawable.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="16dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <stroke
        android:color="@color/colorBlue"
        android:width="2dp" />
</shape>
```

This drawable will be used as EditText's background.
Tag **stroke** makes outline for this shape - set outline width & color here.

in your code

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

ClipDrawable clipDrawable = new ClipDrawable
              (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_text_drawable), 
                    Gravity.BOTTOM, ClipDrawable.VERTICAL);
clipDrawable.setLevel(2000);

editText.setBackground(clipDrawable);
```

Here ClipDrawable "crops" backround drawable.
[ClipDrawable documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ClipDrawable.html)

Comment: thnx for the anser