# how to make full rounded edittext using shape material component?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, material-components

I need to make a full rounded edittext like the image below. I am using Material Component. In material component, we have shape that can be modified right ? so I try to use style to modify the shape, I assume I can modify the edittext shape using style

[image]

using style like this ?

```
<style name="roundedEditText" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">32dp</item>
    </style>
```

and then apply that style to my edittext like this

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_search_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:background="@color/grey_light_top"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Ketik nama ustadz, lokasi, atau acara"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            style="@style/roundedEditText"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/base_searchView_toolbar_keyword_search_result"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/base_searchView_toolbar_keyword_search_result"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView_back_icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/base_searchView_toolbar_keyword_search_result" />
```

but it doesn't make an effect to my edittext, it still a rectangle like this
[image]

if not using shape, can I set it using another way in Material Component ?

Comment: I think you are setting background in the EditText, might be it is overriding property, Check If it is possible to define background in the style itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `TextInputLayout` just use the **`app:shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute:

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.TextInputLayout.Rounded"
        ....

        app:hintEnabled="false"
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/..."
        app:endIconMode="custom"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        ...>
```

with:

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.TextInputLayout.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

If you want to use a simple `ExitText` you can use the [**`MaterialShapeDrawable`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/MaterialShapeDrawable) to [draw custom shapes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md).
[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59454572/2016562).