# How to apply shapeAppreanace in EditText and TextView using Material Design in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-theme, android-styles, material-components-android

I want to design a `TextView` and `EditText` with round corner.

[image]

There is one straight forward solution for this. Using [custom shape background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3646629/5301119).
But since material design 1.1.0 introduces `shapeAppearance` theme attribute to apply a different shape to the corner which works fine for all Material components like `MaterialButton`, `BottomSheet`, `MaterialCardView`, etc.
But it does not work for `EditText` and `TextView`. I tried using `MaterialTextView` as well but it did not work. This how I am setting up style for `EditText` which is similar to `TextView` also.

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.Chat" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="editTextStyle">@style/Overlay.Chat.EditText</item>
    </style>


    <style name="Overlay.Chat.EditText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearance.Overlay.FullRound</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ShapeAppearance.Overlay.FullRound" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.LargeComponent">
        <item name="cornerSize">50dp</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure it's possible but unfortunately there is not enough documentation or examples to begin with :( Need to experiment with this stuff ourselves and implement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can apply the **`MaterialShapeDrawable`** introduced by the Material Components Library also to a `TextView` or `EditText`.
In this case you can't use the `shapeAppearanceOverlay` attribute in your layout or style because these components don't have a `MaterialShapeDrawable` defined by default as the `MaterialButton`, `MaterialCardView`.
But you apply the same `ShapeAppearence` programmatically.

For example:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/secondaryColor"
    ../>
```

Programmatically you can use something like:

```
float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius);
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
```

Define the `ShapeAppearanceModel` with rounded corners:

```
ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = new ShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
        .build();
```

Create a `MaterialShapeDrawable` with this `ShapeAppearanceModel`:

```
MaterialShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel);
```

Apply this background to your view:

```
ViewCompat.setBackground(textView,shapeDrawable);
```

[image]

You can achieve the same behavior with an `EditText` (but you can also use a `TextInputLayout` in this case):

Define in your layout:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
        android:drawableTint="@color/..."
        android:hint="@string/...."
        ..>
```

Then apply the `MaterialShapeDrawable`:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
//Apply the rounded corners 
ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = new ShapeAppearanceModel()
                .toBuilder()
                .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
                .build();

MaterialShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = 
            new MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel);
//Fill the background color
shapeDrawable.setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color....));
//You can also apply a stroke
shapeDrawable.setStroke(2.0f, ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color....));

//Apply the shapeDrawable to the background.
ViewCompat.setBackground(editText,shapeDrawable);
```

[image][image]

If you would like to use `ShapeAppareace` defined in the styles you can use 
the different `ShapeAppearanceModel` constructors. For example:

```
ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel =
            ShapeAppearanceModel.builder( this,
                    R.style.ShapeAppearance_MaterialComponents_MediumComponent,
                    R.style.ShapeOverlay).build();
```

with:

```
<style name="ShapeOverlay">
    <item name="cornerSize">16dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the details answer. 
But how do we change the shapeAppreance dynamically from theme ?. i.e get the shapeAppreance from attr/shapeAppreanceLarge.
Let say I have two themes with different cornerSize in shapeAppreance (8dp and 32dp). How do it will change in the above approach ?

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid Check the updated answer. ShapeAppearanceModel has different constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable resource file with rounded_edittext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
 <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
  android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then in your editText call the created drawable as andriod:background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<EditText  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I think you are good to go.

Comment: I posted the link of this type of solution in the question itself which is a more of hard coded way of doing it. I wanted to have more flexible solution which changes with theme using Material Design themes in Android.

Comment: Did you see this documentation. [link](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields/). This might help you.

Comment: I tried. It works for other Material component. But not for EditText and TextView