# How to round corners of TextView in Android (Java)?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have the following code in my Main-Activity:

```
LinearesLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
LinearesLayout.addView(textView);
```

How can I set the corners of the TextView to round?

Comment: You should try to find a way to do it yourself, first, and show us what you tried if it didn't work and you need help understanding why. 
Don't ask people to do work for you

Comment: @TalMantelmakher I've already tried to find a command for it on the Internet. But how can I show you something if I do not know which command to use?

Comment: It should look somethink like this: textView.setradius="5dp". But i cant finde somethink like this...

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62317455/how-to-apply-shapeappreanace-in-edittext-and-textview-using-material-design-in-a/62318842#62318842

Answer (score 0):

Create an XML file in res\drawable folder - `rounded_corners.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
  <corners android:radius="4dp" />
  <padding
    android:top="5dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:right="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Replace this line:

`textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);`

to this:

`textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corners);`