# How to create a TEdit with rounded corners using Delphi for Android?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm using Delphi 10.3 to develop an Android application. Is there any way to create a `TEdit` that has rounded corners?

Found a link for [How to create EditText with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646415/), how can I do the same thing in Delphi?

Answer (score 3):

You need
TRectanbgle with CornerType Round
and your TEdit on TRectangle (TRectangle will be parent)
All with same backgroud color.
[image]

Comment: I have set TRectangle - XRaxis and YRadius as10 and Set the style as TranspatentEdit for TEdit.and also Trectangle as Parent and Tedit Align as Client. It works fine for. Thanks